# How to parse the JavaScript data

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing, jsoup

This code has live results; can I get the data from this script? Which instruments I can use?

```
<div id="live-table"> 
   <script>
    document.body.classList.toggle("loading", true);
</script> 
   <span class="loadingOverlay"> 
    <div class="loadingAnimation"> 
     <div class="loadingAnimation__text">
      Loading...
     </div> 
    </div></span>
```

Comment: I think Ajax would work as you tagged

Comment: You can make use of jquery also on the code side to get the data from the script.

Comment: i understand,i can used other script to get the data, but I can't  find info how.Can you give me the startpoint, and i'll try to solved this sugesstion.Thank's

Comment: maybe you have piece of code as exaple?